# Couldn't find the final merged executable file location for ILMerge

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, ilmerge

For past few days, I had been struggling with Merging assemblies inside a single executable file. So that I can distribute the single executable file to my users. I found out `ILMerge` to do this apart from `ILMerge`, there are few more tools that seem to do it. I tried `BoxedAPP` Packer and `SmartAssembly` also .`NetShrink` seems to work good but all are paid tools. So, I wanted to complete the task with `ILMerge` and after much of browsing and searching Google and from StackOverflow, I found out the solution.

I tried the below set of lines for merging the assembly

```
c:\"Program Files"\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe"
/lib:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5"
/lib:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"
/t: winexe
/target:exe
/targetplatform:v3.5,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 
/out:”MergedProduct.exe”
"$(TargetDir)Product.exe"
"$(TargetDir)CButtonLib.dll"
"$(TargetDir)Common Tools.dll'
"$(TargetDir)Core.dll"
"$(TargetDir)ProgressIndicator.dll"
"$(TargetDir)TaskScheduler.dll"
```

I used this above set of lines inside 
Build-Events > Post-Build event command line

and after building the project I got as build succeeded. Also while building the application runs as if i have pressed F5 to start debugging. So, to summarize up, I'm sure the above set of lines are correct but i couldn't find the output executable file (i.e `MergedProduct.exe`) anywhere. I also tried using the `Release` mode of the Visual Studio 9.0 but still i couldn't find the Output merged executable.

Is there something really obvious that i'm missing?

Also, can I merge `Product.exe.config` file using `ILMerge`?

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that codeblock a cut and past of the command line? I notice you have fancy quotes around the /out filename. Also, have you tried adding a folder to the /out filename (eg, $(TargetDir))? We do that in our build process to save it in a particular publish folder.

ILMerge will allow you to merge the xml documentation, but not the configuration files (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: No, that code block actually contains the the names of the dll files that im using in my project, apart from the .exe. This works good for me. I have even tried using the output folder that u have specified. But didnt work. So in the end we got the task done with some thrid party license tool. But i would still like to know how it can be done using ILMERGE.

Comment: Can you add the logging switch `/log:<filename>` where `<filename>` can include a fully qualified path. With luck the log should shed some light on what is going wrong. Additionally, are you able to try this directly from the command line to avoid any "complications" that the IDE might introduce.

Comment: In fact so far i havent included any log file. But it seems a good idea. I didnt know that it can be done. But the thing is that when i type the above set of lines inside the Command line interface and build the project. The project gets built i dont get any error. Then how come im not getting any output merged assembly.? This is what which is troubling me.

Comment: Well hopefully we can determine the issue by looking at the log file.

Comment: Also, I don't know how accurate that code block is, but you have an extra quote in the first line (around Program Files, then one more at the end)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very much appreciated help, I tried it and got it done. Thanks for your help.